# How to validate XML files against XSD (automatically)?

Tags: validation, xml-file

we have a module in our architecture which checks a SFTP(server)directory for new transmitted XML files, validates them against XSD and if successful it takes the XML file from the directory and does something with it.

My question is now: What is a good/the best way to tests this module automically. I know I could create XML files and check them against an XSD in eclipse using JAXB. But I want to create something like this:

- Design a set of XML files which fail/pass the XSD-Valiadation
- Run these tests automically (Maven [/Jenkisn])

Whats the best way to do this? Putting the XML files in the `test/ressources` folder of the maven module and writing JUnitTests which reads the testXMLS and the XSD and checks them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are the developer of the system or not but generally speaking it is the responsibility of the devs to write Unit Test (If you are a QA, remind them). Assuming that, as you mentioned "Design a set of XML files which fail/pass the XSD-Valiadation" is enough.

If you are interested in high-level test, then maybe you want to have a look at [SOAP UI](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/validating-xml-messages.html).

Comment: I'm somewhere in between dev and QA but more QA I think ;) It's good to see that my thoughts about Unit Tests seems a viable way but I dont think SOAP UI is a good way because of Continious Integration as even if it's possible to call SOAP UI via commandline or something like this I can then use java itself. I will accept your answer in a few days for the case then someone else maybe has another solution. But be sure that I daily visit SQA.SE